# XML returning NoneType object has no attribute text when the value exists and shouldn't return None

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing, urllib

So I'm building a script to fetch data from XML and store in a database but in the end it says that the value `purl` returns None but after inspecting the XML file its none and exists so I don't understand why it's returning None.

Is this a time problem where I'm making things too fast or a real problem?

Here is the code:

```
class Colectors(object):
    ENGINE = db.create_engine(f'mysql+pymysql://{MYSQL_USER}:{MYSQL_PASSWORD}@{MYSQL_HOST}:3306/{MYSQL_DB}',
                              pool_size=20, max_overflow=0)

    def __init__(self):
        self.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

    def sql_query(self, query):
        conn = self.ENGINE.connect()
        response = conn.execute(query)
        conn.close()
        return response

    def AWIN(self, brand, brand_id, feed_url, country_id, category_id):
        req = urllib.request.Request(feed_url, headers=self.headers)
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
        root = ET.fromstring(response)
        for product in tqdm(root.findall('product'), desc='PRODUCT COLLECTION'):
            # Build name with options
            try:
                name = str(product.find('name').text)
                try:
                    if str(product.find('custom3').text) != name:
                        name = name + ' ' + str(product.find('custom3').text)
                except: pass
                try:
                    if str(product.find('custom4').text) != name:
                        name = name + ' ' + str(product.find('custom4').text)
                except: pass
                # End name build
                ean = str(product.find('ean').text)
                price = float(product.find('price').find('actualp').text)
                discount_price = 0
                shipping = float(product.find('delivery_cost').text)
                stock = int(product.find('instock').text)
                currency = str(product.find('currency').text)
                try:
                    main_img = str(product.find('imgurl').text)
                except:
                    main_img = str(product.find('alternate_image_two').text)
                imgs = []
                try:
                    x = str(product.find('alternate_image_two').text)
                    if main_img != x:
                        imgs.append(x)
                except: pass
                try:
                    x = str(product.find('alternate_image_three').text)
                    imgs.append(x)
                except: pass
                try:
                    x = str(product.find('alternate_image_four').text)
                    imgs.append(x)
                except: pass
                url = str(product.find('purl').text)
                description = str(product.find('desc').text)

                # Check if this is a new product or its already added to DB
                resp = self.sql_query(f"SELECT id FROM products_data.products WHERE EAN='{ean}'")
                if resp.rowcount == 0:
                    now = datetime.now()
                    if discount_price != 0 and discount_price < price:
                        data = {str(date.today()): discount_price}
                    else:
                        data = {str(date.today()): price}
                    query = "INSERT INTO products_data.products (name, url, category_id, country_id, price, currency, discount_price, shipping, brand_id, description, stock, rating, main_image, images, SKU, EAN, GTIN, last_update, created_date, price_history)" \
                            "VALUES (:name, :url, :category_id, :country_id, :price, :currency, :discount_price, :shipping, :brand, :description, :stock, :rating, :main_img, :imgs, :SKU, :EAN, :GTIN, :now, :now2, :history)"
                    query = db.text(query)
                    query = query.bindparams(name=name, category_id=category_id, country_id=country_id, price=price, currency=currency, discount_price=0, shipping=shipping, brand=brand_id, description=description, stock=stock, rating=0,
                                             main_img=main_img, imgs=json.dumps(imgs), SKU=None, EAN=ean, GTIN=None, now=now, now2=now, history=json.dumps(data), url=url)
                    self.sql_query(query)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                pass
```

The output:

```
PRODUCT COLLECTION:  89%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████▏                                       | 1094/1231 [04:41<00:35,  3.88it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "feed_collector.py", line 122, in <module>
    Worker().get_feeds()
  File "feed_collector.py", line 117, in get_feeds
    Colectors().AWIN(brand, id, feed_url, country_id, category_id)
  File "feed_collector.py", line 69, in AWIN
    url = str(product.find('purl').text)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

The XML file:

```
https://www.theproteinworks.com/media/feeds/AK_DFM_UK_AWIN.xml
```

As you can see this XML is big but every purl tag has content so I don't know what's causing this problem.

Comment: You have a single product without a purl for a start... as well as a few bits that once you've resolved that are going to cause some interesting things to pop up :)

Comment: @JonClements I have it to skip if it can't get the URL but still I don't know why its having so many trouble finding the products and when it goes to the next feed that has the same layout it gets like 10 products and skips most of them